# POSIX Regex - finding "a2bcd" in "jd-ednl\a2bcdn44"

Tags: regex, posix

i am trying to look for regex syntax to find "a2bcd" in "jd-ednl\a2bcdn44"

so far i've tried (a2bcd) and ^a2bcd.* but nothing seems to work. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual code you are using to run this regex?

Comment: When you find it, what do you want to do with it? Is it enough to say "it is in this line", "it is in this file", "replace it with xxx", "strip everything that is not a2bcd"... Please clarify your question to get a better (more useful) answer. A literal string matches a literal string... So that can't be your question. Can it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using grep or similar that searches through the string to find a match, then `a2bcd` will work. Otherwise if you need to match the whole string, try `^.*a2bcd.*$`.